# How to detect the message arrival time for WCF MSMQ binding

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq

I have a service using WCF MSMQ binding. On the server, it is needed to introduce some latency, for example 5 seconds. To do that, the service wants to detect the time when the message arrives.

I searches through OperationContex.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders, and OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties but can not find the property.

Is there anyway to get this timestamp?

Comment: Why would you want to add latency to a message, this smells like a race condition?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is such a property on message headers - unless you add it as a custom header on the way out... then you could extract that..?

Are you after throttling by any chance??? See for example [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751436(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)